# Cipher for human interpretation

Tags: encryption

Please suggest algorithms to encrypt and decrypt text messages that can be easily performed by human in a considerably short time. It doesn't have to be really secure, but sufficient to fool unskillful third parties.

Comment: "Unskillful" is a very vague term. How do you define it? Anyway, considering your requirement that it should be easily performed by a human in a very short time, I don't believe there would be anything better than [Vigenère cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigen%C3%A8re_cipher) or a [One-Time Pad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad)

Comment: What research have you done? This is quite off-topic, because it is just a reference request (or a duplicate of the mentioned question)

Answer (score 0):

I think Caesar cipher meets your requiremnts, check it out here [Caesar Cipher](http://www.cs.trincoll.edu/~crypto/historical/caesar.html)